# PHP Curl Do Loop

Tags: php, loops, curl

I am sending some contracts through esignatures, I am trying to loop through a list of people to send a batch of contracts all at once.  After the first person it exits. Any ideas why?

```
    do {
            $curl_request = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://mykey:@esignatures.io/api/contracts');
            curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "
                {\"template_id\":\"template_id\",
                    \"test\": \"yes\", 
                    \"signers\":
                        [{
                            \"name\":\"signer one\",
                            \"email\":\"email@email.com\",
                            \"mobile\":\"1234567890\",
                            \"signing_order\":\"1\",
                            \"auto_sign\":\"yes\",
                            \"skip_signature_request\":\"yes\"},{
                            \"name\":\"$buyername\",
                            \"email\":\"$email\",
                            \"mobile\":\"$cell\",
                            \"signing_order\":\"2\",
                            \"auto_sign\":\"no\",
                            \"skip_signature_request\":\"no\"
                        }],
                    \"placeholder_fields\":
                        [{
                            \"api_key\":\"test\",
                            \"value\":\"$test\"},{
                            \"api_key\":\"data\",
                            \"value\":\"$data\"
                        }]
                }");

            curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            $headers = array();
            $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
            curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
            $result = curl_exec($curl_request);
            curl_close ($curl_request);
    } while ($myrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result));
```

Comment: `while ($myrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result));` 
Are you sure this code return true?

Sending HTTP requests in loops is not recommended!
It can cause obstruction.
And you don't know if the request is successful, because you didn't process the result

Comment: Please, show the query you are executing as if the `while` is exiting in after the first run, then there are no results... show us all your code or we will not be able to help you...

Comment: `$result` used for `mysqli_fetch_assoc` is overloaded in `$result = curl_exec($curl_request);`.

Comment: @syscall - Bingo! I completely missed that I had the same variable for both of those. That fixed it.  Thank you!